# I want to format(properly) pendrive which has linux installed on it on windows

Tags: windows-7, linux, usb, usb-flash-drive

I used dd command in linux to do byte-copy of a linux-distro iso. I installed it on a computer, I don't have access to that computer, to reformat my pendrive using mkfs.vfat.

In windows only 456 MB(size of live-image in pendrive) is recoverable, I had this experience before. But I did format using a linux distro.

I don't have access to any linux computer, nor can i install linux on the current windows(7) computer.

I need to get full 4GB space of the pendrive  in FAT32. Is there an utility for windows, to do this task?

Comment: Wha happens if you simply format the drive in Windows? Or if you delete all partitions and recreate them using a partition manager?

Comment: I get back only 456 MB space back.

Comment: You can use a virtual machine.

Comment: You get only 456 when doing what? Deleting data? Formatting from Windows? Or if you [re-create the partition table](http://www.howtogeek.com/101862/how-to-manage-partitions-on-windows-without-downloading-any-other-software/)?

Comment: current computer has like 1024 MB RAM and crappy graphics. I tried booting a headless arch in virtualbox, it only took like 40 minutes.

Comment: @terdon Formatting from Windows

Comment: @tedron only partition it is showing on the pendrive is of size 456 MB. I am sure only that much i will get back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you seem to have created a single partition of 456 MB on your pendrive. You should be able to use the entire drive if you delete that partition and create a new one that is as large as the drive allows. Follow these steps (adapted from [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/101862/how-to-manage-partitions-on-windows-without-downloading-any-other-software/)):

1. Type “Partition” into the search box in the Control Panel or Start menu and click the “Create and Format Hard Disk Partitions” option that comes up:

   [image]
2. You should see a window like this one, listing all the drives attached to your computer, including your pendrive:

   [image]
3. Select your pendrive, right click and select "Delete Volume"
4. Now select the unallocated space of your pendrive, right click and select "New Simple Volume"
5. Follow the wizard to create a partition that takes up all available space.